# How to find and remove words which have low and high idf values?

Tags: python, tfidfvectorizer

I am finding filtering words based on their idf values.I have 36k words in a list & i have idf values of 24k words from the list.Now , How do i map each word with their idf values , so that it becomes easy to filter.

I have stored all the unique words(36k) from a dataframe & i have idf values of 24k of them

```
a=list(project_data['final_input_text'].str.split(' ', expand=True).stack().unique())
```

I expect words mapped to their idf values, either in a dictionary or a dataframe

Comment: please share a sample of the lists

Comment: ...yes, a sample of the two input lists and also a sample of the desired output.  What constitutes a "high" or "low" idf value?  You need to more completely define the problem.

Comment: i have words from dataframe in my list a.After  plotting a box plot , i need to remove words with idf<8 and idf>10. I have the words 

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
vectorizer.fit(a)

idf = vectorizer.idf_

i got idf values of the words ,which is in idf, now how do i map them?

Comment: ok , i got it :)   
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
train_tf=vectorizer.fit(train['final_input_text'].values)
dict(zip(train_tf.get_feature_names(), idf))

Answer (score 3):

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer 
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer() 
train_tf = vectorizer.fit(train['final_input_text'].values) 
idf_scores = train_tf.idf_
```

filtering the indices based on lower thrshold value = 8 and higher thrshold value = 11

```
filtered_indices = np.argwhere(((idf_scores> 8) & (idf_scores<11.55) ))
filtered_indices = [idx[0] for idx in filtered_indices]

#list of vocabulary from the vectorizer
vocabulary = train_tf.get_feature_names()

#preparing a set with filtered vocabulary
filtered_voc = {vocabulary[i] for i in filtered_indices}
```

removing the words (which are not in filtered voc) from essays

```
filtered_text_list = []
for text in train['final_input_text'].values:
  text_word_list = [word for word in text.split() if word in filtered_voc]
  filtered_text_list.append(' '.join(text_word_list))
```

And now filtered_text_list will not contain any word which has low(<8) and high(>11) idf values

Comment: This solution is very expensive!

Is there any other way to do so?